# Reading a file - where does '(#<void> ... #<void>) come from?

Tags: scheme, racket, void, map-function

The following code is meant to display read text line-by-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(require racket/string)
(require racket/file)


(require racket/file)
(display "Line by line with for loop:\n\n")
(define f "../file-to-be-read.short")
(define content (file->lines f))
(for ([l content]) (display l))
  
(define (do-sth-to-each-line fn-name) 
  (define f "../file-to-be-read.short")
  (define content (file->lines f))
  (map fn-name content))

(display "\n\nAnd now line by line with map and display:\n\n")
(do-sth-to-each-line display)
```

the code reads from `../file-to-be-read.short` whose content is:

```
Not that I think you did not love your father,

But that I know love is begun by time,

And that I see, in passages of proof,

Time qualifies the spark and fire of it.
```

The result of the call to `(do-sth-to-each-line display)` is the following:

```
Not that I think you did not love your father,But that I know love is begun by time,And that I see, in passages of proof,Time qualifies the spark and fire of it.'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

Where does `'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)` come from? Why doesn't `(for ([l content]) (display l))` produce such unintended by me output?

Comment: Your are seeing the effects, and then the resulting value, of your last function call. Whose last call is to `map display ...`. (and `fn-name` is not a function's name, but already its value the function, because Scheme is *call-by-value* i.e. the arguments' values are found *before* the function call is made.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#<void>` is return value for `display` function, so `'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)` is result of `map` `display` over `content` (`map` and `for` both produce list of results, so `for` returns the same result).

If you want to run some side effect for each element in the list, you should rather use [`for-each`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29).

Also, don't use `define` inside `define`, use [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) for introducing local variables, and consider using [`displayln`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmisc..rkt%29._displayln%29%29):

```
#lang racket
(require racket/string)
(require racket/file)

(define (print-file filename) 
  (for-each displayln
            (file->lines filename)))

(displayln "Now line by line with for-each and displayln:")
(print-file "../file-to-be-read.short")
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `for-each` got rid of `'(#<void> ... #<void>).` `#<void>` is the return value of `display` and `displayln`. Why then is it so that `'(#<void> ... #<void>).` appears when calling these functions on every element of a list with `map` and doesn't it appear when calling them within a `for` loop or with `for-each`?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation, [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) returns list (= list of results) and [`for-each`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29) returns [`#<void>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._void~3f%29%29).

Answer (score 2):

A better way to use `for` for this is:

```lisp
(define (display-file filename)
  (call-with-input-file filename
    (lambda (port) (for ([line (in-lines port)]) (display line)))))
```

[`in-lines`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-lines%29%29) returns a sequence that iterates over lines read from a port one at a time instead of reading the entire file into a list first, making it use a lot less memory on large input files.

There's also [`display-lines`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._display-lines%29%29) as an alternative to `for-each` (Which as pointed out by Martin is better than `map` here), though it too requires the entire input file to be read first:

```lisp
(display-lines (file->lines filename) #:separator #\u200C)
```

It just displays every element of the given list, with a separator character between then (Defaults to `#\newline` making it act like `displayln` of each element instead of `display`). In this case to mimic the behavior of the other versions that don't insert anything between lines, [U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON JOINER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) is used as the separator character to get the same visual effect when looking at the output in Unicode-aware programs. `#\space` is another option, since ZWNJ might cause unexpected effects on non-ASCII text (As can *not* having a separator between lines).

Comment: Thanks. Is `call-with-input-file` something alike to the context manager in Python. Does it  handle closing the port automatically, without me having to explicitly instruct about it later on?

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't know python, but, yes, `call-with-input-file` automatically closes the file port when it returns. See [the documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file%29%29).